# MySQL FIND_IN_SET with ODER BY

Tags: mysql

I am having difficulty with this MySQL query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM auth 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET ('baseUser',authTypes)>0; ORDER BY parent_id DESC
```

The ORDER BY clause is not working. The authTypes column in the auth table is defined set('baseUser','advUser','adminUser',...).

```
SELECT * FROM auth ORDER BY parent_id DESC
```

does order as expected.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET ('baseUser',authTypes)>0;` there is `;` at the end, remove it

Comment: @safarov I suggest making your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FIND_IN_SET ('baseUser',authTypes)>0;` there is `;` at the end, remove it

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I can see the trees for the forest.